# Insert new row based on condition

Tags: r

I would like to insert `efficiently` (as I have 1mil. row df) new row if given `id` occurs only once.

Here sample data and desired result:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,6,6,6,101),year=c(2012,2013,2014,2011,2012,2013,2015),value1=rnorm(7),value2=rexp(7),value3=rpois(7,2))


df <- transform(df, rec=ave(df$id, df$id, FUN=seq_along))

dfL <- df[!duplicated(df$id, fromLast=TRUE), ]
dfL[dfL$rec==1, ][-ncol(dfL)]
```

The desired result for the above already selected 2 rows:

```
id year    value1    value2 value3
2  2013      ""        ""     ""
2  2014   0.7345321 0.1449742  3
101 2014   ""          ""     ""
101 2015  0.2547620 0.7166841  1
```

For the whole data set it would be:

```
id  year  value1     value2      value3 
1   2012 -1.38007779 2.97957329      2  
1   2013 -0.03257949 0.92996719      1   
2   2013  ""         ""              ""
2   2014  0.73453214 0.14497416      3   
6   2011 -1.04242748 0.03099297      0   
6   2012  0.35932001 0.90399050      3   
6   2013  1.18300395 0.29446006      1   
101 2014  ""        ""              ""
101 2015  0.25476203 0.71668415      1
```

Comment: How do you want to fill the 'year' column.  Please use `set.seed` to make this reproducible.

Comment: as integer please. @akrun: the numbers are just example, it doesn't matter for this case.

Comment: But are the values that should be filled in `year`? One year before? For example a quick solution could be just `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, if(.N < 2) .SD[2:1] else .SD, by = id]`

Comment: @David: that's the point, the years are not there for the new rows to be filled.

Comment: I would try with `setDT(df)[, if(.N==1) .SD[1:(.N+1)] else .SD, id]` and filling the year is not clear

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to fill the years or not?

Comment: yes, I need the years as well, always 1 year less as the current year.

Comment: It may not be the most efficient solution, but you can get there with dplyr: `df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(n() ==1) %>% mutate(year= year-1, value1 = NA, value2 = NA, value3 = NA) %>% bind_rows(df) %>%arrange(id)`. I used NA rather than "" because it didn't like combining numeric data with strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something as the following

```
library(data.table); 
setDT(df)[, if(.N < 2L) {
               .SD[c(NA_real_, 1L)][, year := c(year[2L] - 1L, year[2L])]
          } else .SD,
          by = id]
#     id year     value1     value2 value3
# 1:   1 2012 -1.6552064 0.05040943      4
# 2:   1 2013  1.3478321 1.08314748      2
# 3:   2 2013         NA         NA     NA
# 4:   2 2014  0.2320925 0.45546268      0
# 5:   6 2011  0.5110803 0.07412734      2
# 6:   6 2012  0.5170348 0.29052181      0
# 7:   6 2013  0.6925863 0.09309213      3
# 8: 101 2014         NA         NA     NA
# 9: 101 2015  1.6719612 0.84413431      4
```

This is basically checks per group if it's larger than 1 (`.N` denote the size of the group), if so it returns it as is (`.SD` denotes the **S**ub**D**ata which is the data within a specific group), if not, it replicates the whole row twice (subsets `.SD` by its first value and some nonexistent `NA` value) for that id and fills the missing year (I'm assigning it to column `year` using the `:=` operator while subsetting from the non-`NA` year (`year[2] - 1L`) one year an adding it with that year itself(`year[2]`))

Comment: now I just found out that it doesn't work with my real data: `Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df), , if (.N < 2) { : 
  Column 57 of result for group 3 is type 'double' but expecting type 'integer'. Column types must be consistent for each group.`

Comment: I cannot adapt your code since I don't know data.table, it seems that it has issue with `class`

Comment: Can you show a `dput(head(df, 20))` of your real data? Also, what `data.able` version you have?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot disclose the nature of the data. I have to work it out with base R. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @akrun that's fine, I'm sure your both solutions are more efficient.

Comment: yes, indeed it works!! Great! Yes, I will accept David's answer. Sorry guys for this confusion. My bad!

Answer (score 2):

We could get the row index (`.I`) for 'id's that have only a single element (`.N==1`), subset the dataset with that index, subtract 1 from the 'year' column,  assign (`:=`) the 'value' columns to `NA`, `rbind` with the original dataset, and then `order` the rows of the resulting dataset.

```
ind <- setDT(df)[,.I[.N==1], by = id]$V1
DT <- rbind(df,
         df[ind][, list(year=year-1) ,.(id)][,names(df)[3:ncol(df)] := NA])
DT[order(id, year)]
#     id year      value1     value2 value3
#1:   1 2012 -0.03373792 0.28790583      0
#2:   1 2013 -0.58542756 1.02799997      2
#3:   2 2013          NA         NA     NA
#4:   2 2014  0.61285136 0.13438167      1
#5:   6 2011  1.51712249 0.63349530      1
#6:   6 2012  0.65738044 2.86740657      1
#7:   6 2013 -1.07418134 0.43519879      1
#8: 101 2014          NA         NA     NA
#9: 101 2015 -4.46956441 0.05370307      4
```

NOTE: It would be better to have `NA` instead of `''` as assigning to `''` will also change the `class` of the columns.

---

The `rbind` approach can be also done with `base R`.  We get the count of 'id' using `table`, `subset` the original dataset based on the table output, `transform` the 'year' column by subtracting 1, get the column index ('indx') of 'value' as column names (`grep`), multiply those columns with `NA` to change those columns to `NA`, `rbind` the two datasets and `order` the dataset based on 'id' and 'year' column.

```
tbl <- table(df$id)==1
df1 <- transform(subset(df, id %in% names(tbl)[tbl]), year=year-1)
indx <- grep('value', colnames(df1))  
df1[indx] <- df1[indx]*NA
df2 <- rbind(df, df1)
df2[order(df2$id, df2$year),]
```

Comment: it would be great to have the column names automatically assigned independently. Like `names(df)[3:ncol]` or something like that. Thanks.

Comment: @Maximilian  Edited the post using your comments.  Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the base R. Won't be efficient but at least will work since I can adapt to my needs. Thanks.

Comment: The base R solution will be efficient two. Its fully vectorized.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Your code is very elegant.  Could you be able to fix with `NA_real_`?